# im having a manifest json error and i don't know how to fix

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

i have a chrome extension that started returning the manifest error "the manifest.json file is missing or unreadable". I don't know what to do, tried to fix it several times but nothing

```json
{
  "name": "HytesCord SuperBlack",
  "short_name":"SuperBlack",
  "description": "This browser extension enables the Discord mobile AMOLED Super Black theme in your discord browser.",
  "version": "2.0.2",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/hytesImages/HytescordIcon_48b.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/hytesImages/HytescordIcon_128b.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The error is that the file is "missing or unreadable" - showing the file here is of no use - something is stopping the file from being readable ... a filesystem permission?

Comment: The `icons` block is entirely wrong, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons).

Comment: @Bravo i don't know, it looks like chrome don't even try to read it